# Cache Message Source

Tags: caching, spring-boot

For each call on the Message Source implementation, I would like to do a cache before call the remote server.

Here is the pseudo code.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationForMessageSource {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {

        return new AbstractMessageSource() {

            @Autowired
            RemoteMessageSource remoteMessageSource;

            @Override
            protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {

                String message = remoteMessageSource.translate(code);

                return createMessageFormat(message, locale);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The service implementation

```
@Service
public class RemoteMessageSource {

    @Cacheable(value = "message", key = "#code")
    public String translate(String code) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return dataBase.get(code);
    }
}
```

A full implementation is available at github: [spring-boot-cache-messagesource](https://github.com/diegolovison/spring-boot-cache-messagesource)